# Django channels безопасность

Tags: django, django-channels

изучаю django channels и возникла такая проблема: допустим у меня роутинг каналов происходит так:

```py
from django.urls import re_path

from .consumers import ChatConsumer

websocket_urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r'^ws/chat/(?P<id>[^/]+)/$', ChatConsumer),
]
```

получается, что любой кто знает номер канала, может прослушивать сообщения которые ходят по этому адресу.
Может можно как-нибудь во время коннекта к сокету отправлять данные(токен к примеру)? Спасибо.